# Can I sell the excess alien technologies?

Tags: x-com-terror-from-the-deep

I running out of storage space, and I have noticed that I have a multiple pieces of unresearched alien components and technologies, is it enough if I only keep 1 from each or will I need more for manufacturing crafts/buildings/equipment ?

[image]

Comment: Selling things must be possible because there are [manufacturing for profit](https://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php/Buying/Selling/Transferring_(TFTD)) pages, but I don't remember how to sell things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold on to *Zrbite* and *Aqua Plastic*. They are required to construct a wide variety of items and will only get more important over the course of the game.

*Ion Beam Accelerator* and *Magnetic Navigation* are required for building alien technology submarines. But you only need 1 of them each for most subs (the best one requires two ion beam accelerators and one navigation). You are not going to build that many subs, you can build these components yourself if you need to and you will farm plenty more of these over the course of the game. So it might make sense to hoard *a few* of these if building subs is something you want to do in the near future, but it doesn't makes sense to hoard as many as you already got. If you have already researched them and are currently satisfied with your tritons and barracudas, you might want to consider to get rid of them all.

The following items are research-only items. You can sell all but one if you haven't researched them yet. When they are researched, you can sell them all:

- Alien Cryogenics
- Alien Cloning
- Alien Learning Arrays
- Alien Implanter
- Alien Sub Construction
- Examination Room
- Alien Re-animation Zone
- Any Alien Corpses